# WIF SessionAuthenticationModule CookieHandler not writing FedAuth cookie

Tags: cookies, wif, federated-identity

I am having trouble getting Windows Identity Framework to write the FedAuth cookie under certain circumstances. I am picking up the development of a suite of MVC4 websites which already use WIF and successfully write the FedAuth cookie for their own domain. Now I am trying to get the cookie written for each domain in my suite.

On my development machine, I have three websites hosted locally by IIS7.5 (app1.mycompany.com, app2.mycompany.com and app3.DIFFDOMAIN.com). When I sign into app1, I set the cookie's domain to "mycompany.com" which means *both* app1 and app2 are federated but I can't find a good way to get app3 included.

```
FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule
                       .CookieHandler.Domain = "mycompany.com".
```

Things I have noticed / tried so far:

1. In app1, I can set Domain = "app1.mycompany.com" or "mycompany.com" and the cookie is written but if I set it to anything else the cookie isn't written *therefore there must be some underlying validation of the Domain property when writing the cookie*. Is that true??
2. I wrote an API service in app3 to be called from app1 (e.g. `https://app3.DIFFDOMAIN.com/fedauth`) which sets Domain = "DIFFDOMAIN.com".

   - When I call the api from a browser, the cookie is written.
   - When I call the api from app1 using a rest client, the cookie *is not* written.
   - When I RedirectPermanent from app1 to app3 url, the cookie is written (but I don't really want to redirect).

**So I guess I'm asking why the cookie is not written when using a rest client and also how should I federate authentication on all domains**?

Thanks,
John.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that I got you. In general WIF SAM module is in charge for handling of the FedAuth cookies. It is automatically doing this if it is configured properly in your web config. FedAuth cookie contains issued STS token. FAM module is intercepting all requests and redirect those that need authorization to the STS. After authentication on STS, SAM module is creating cookie or combination with session (depends on configuration) and place it in the client browser under the specific domain. SAM and WAF are not responsible to federate authentication on all domains, but STS is. STS is placing its own cookie in clients browser, so with each succeeding call from different domain STS will now depend on that cookie that user is logged on, and will automatically send token to that domain with set of claims.

You have to set up configuration for all domains. Only that, other is business of WIF.
Second is to set up your STS, you can find samples online.

To get complete process in detail, please take a look on this great article :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff872350.aspx

I hope that this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're missing 2 points (try to get [more information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff872350.aspx) on them to get clearer view):

- **How cookies work and what are they used for**. Trying to set a cookie for any other client than one you're just communicating with or for any other domain than yours is considered insecure. When your federated application stores authentication data, it converts it into a FedAuth cookie which is sent to the authenticated client. The client sends the cookie back on the subsequent requests and the server unwraps it to "know" user's authentication.
- **How federated authentication works**. Each fedarated application (RP) in your environment asks STS service to authenticate the user. STS sends an authenticating token to the RP which stores it somehow to be able to distinguish it's users.

Both of these relationships *is one to one*. Client-application and application-STS. There is no need to share authentication information of one client session with anybody else. Why? The client authenticates with STS and STS sends this information to any RP that wants to authenticate this client. The applications don't share information with each other, only with single one STS.